# Binding to two properties

Tags: .net, wpf, binding

I have an interesting scenario- I have a slider that needs to update a control immediately as its value is changed.  All good there, easy.

But I would ALSO like it to do some additional work, but only after a delay.  The .NET 4.5 delay property on bindings would be perfect, but now the slider value needs to have two bindings... one with a delay and one without.

Something like the equivalent of this:

```
<Slider value={Binding Path=Property1, Delay=500; Binding Path=Property2} />
```

I know this doesn't exist but it would be nice to have.  But is there a way to do this using the new Delay prop from 4.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will work but you could cheat a bit using `MultiBinding` with a dummy converter.

Something like:

xaml:

```
   <Window.Resources>
        <local:DummyConverter x:Key="Dummyconverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Slider >
            <Slider.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Dummyconverter}" >
                    <Binding Path="Value1"  />
                    <Binding Path="Value2" Delay="500" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Slider.Value>
        </Slider>
    </Grid>
```

Dummy Converter

```
public class DummyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values == null ? null : values[0];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new object[] { value, value };
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't mind cheating a bit with this... :) Ill try this out, thanks!